# Edit a blob image in JavaScript (Resize and add Border)

Tags: javascript, image, resize, border, edit

Could someone please help me with this situation:

1. I have to retrieve images (stored in BLOB) from an Oracle SQL Database. 
   This is already done and images are pushed into a temporary attribute in HEX.
2. These images are later pushed to a Directory Server using LDAP.

The only problem is, that I want to resize each image to a specific size and add a simple border on the fly using Javascript without using the file system of the host, before pushing them to the LDAP Directory Server.
Note: I can't use browser specific methods or objects, since my java runtime is used by a different host rather than a browser.

It's been a week since I am looking for a solution and unfortunately, I haven't found one yet.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
Bobby

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning Oracle and LDAP makes me think that your JS runtime is not a browser. But if it is, you can use canvas for both resizing and adding border, you can then get the data back as data URL using `canvasEl.toDataURL('image/png')`. Read up on how to use canvas https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, it's not a browser, it's a product by IBM called Tivoli Directory Integrator.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can execute system commands from there, you could run imagemagick command line tools to do the job, then grab the result.